# Trying to dynamically generate tabs on a JTabbedPane with content but getting an Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java, swing, awt, indexoutofboundsexception, jtabbedpane

I am trying to dynamically generate tabs and their containing textfields based on input given by the user. The input is noTCPFlows in the code shown. But when I run the code I keep getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setTitleAt(JTabbedPane.java:1316)
    at myproject.ns2GUI.trafficInfoInit(ns2GUI.java:622)
    at myproject.ns2GUI.flowDetailsContinueActionPerformed(ns2GUI.java:567)
    at myproject.ns2GUI.access$200(ns2GUI.java:16)
    at myproject.ns2GUI$3.actionPerformed(ns2GUI.java:343)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

and nothing is displayed on screen.

I have shown the code below. Can someone please help?

```
package myproject;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ns2GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private CardLayout laycard;

    public int noTCPFlows,noUDPFlows,totalFlows;


    public ns2GUI() {
        initComponents();
        laycard = new CardLayout();
        mainPanel.setLayout(laycard);
        mainPanel.add("scenarioParameters",scenarioParameters);
        mainPanel.add("nodeVisualization",nodeVisualization);
        mainPanel.add("flowDetails",flowDetails);
        mainPanel.add("trafficInfo",trafficInformation);
        laycard.show(mainPanel,"scenarioParameters");
    }

    public void goScenarioParams() {
        laycard.show(mainPanel,"scenarioParameters");
    }

    public void goNodeVisualization() {
        laycard.show(mainPanel,"nodeVisualization");
    }

    public void goFlowDetails() {
        laycard.show(mainPanel,"flowDetails");
    }

    public void goTrafficInfo() {
        laycard.show(mainPanel,"trafficInfo");
    }



    private void scenarioParamsClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        simTime.setText(" ");
        noNodes.setText(" ");
        tSizeX.setText(" ");
        tSizeY.setText(" ");
        initEnergy.setText(" ");
        transmitPower.setText(" ");
        recPower.setText(" ");
    }                                                   

    private void scenarioParamsOkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        goFlowDetails();
    }                                                

    private void enterDetailsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        srcSinkPanel.removeAll();
        srcSinkPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        noTCPFlows = Integer.parseInt(noTcpFlows.getText());
        noUDPFlows = Integer.parseInt(noUdpFlows.getText());
        totalFlows = noTCPFlows + noUDPFlows;
        String tcpLabel = "TCP Flow ";
        String udpLabel = "UDP Flow ";
        String source = "source";
        String sink = "sink";
        String panel = "panel";

        int gridSize = 3;
        int i = 0;

            //loop for TCP flows
            for(int k=0;k<noTCPFlows; k++) {
                JLabel jL = new JLabel(tcpLabel + k);
                JTextField jT1 = new JTextField(source + k,10);
                JTextField jT2 = new JTextField(sink + k,10);
                jT1.setText(" ");
                jT2.setText(" ");
                String panelName = panel + i++;
                JPanel jP = new JPanel();
                jP.add(jL);
                jP.add(jT1);
                jP.add(jT2);
                jP.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, gridSize ) );
                srcSinkPanel.add(jP);
            }

            //loop for UDP flows
            for(int j=0;j<noUDPFlows; j++) {
                JLabel jL = new JLabel(udpLabel + j);
                JTextField jT1 = new JTextField(source + j,10);
                JTextField jT2 = new JTextField(sink + j,10);
                jT1.setText(" ");
                jT2.setText(" ");
                String panelName = panel + i++;
                JPanel jP = new JPanel();
                jP.add(jL);
                jP.add(jT1);
                jP.add(jT2);
                jP.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, gridSize ) );
                srcSinkPanel.add(jP);
            }

            //add the Source Sink panel
            srcSinkPanel.revalidate();


    }                                            

    private void flowDetailsBackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        goScenarioParams();
    }                                               

    private void flowDetailsContinueActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        goTrafficInfo();
        trafficInfoInit();
    }                                                   

    public void trafficInfoInit() {
        String tabName = "tab";
        String tcpLabel = "TCP Flow";
        String udpLabel = "UDP Flow ";
        String[] flowType = {"CBR","FTP","Exponential"};
        int countTcp = 1;
        int countUdp = 1;

        //Main Panel contents
        JPanel[] jP = new JPanel[noTCPFlows];
        JLabel[] jL =new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JComboBox[] jCb = new JComboBox[noTCPFlows];

        //option panels
        JPanel[] cbrParams = new JPanel[noTCPFlows];
        JPanel[] expoParams = new JPanel[noTCPFlows];
        JPanel[] ftpParams = new JPanel[noTCPFlows];

        //CBR Contents
        JLabel[] jL1Cbr = new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JLabel[] jL2Cbr = new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JLabel[] jL3Cbr = new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JLabel[] jL4Cbr = new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JTextField[] cbrPacketSize = new JTextField[noTCPFlows];
        JTextField[] cbrRate = new JTextField[noTCPFlows];
        JTextField[] cbrInterPacketInt = new JTextField[noTCPFlows];
        JTextField[] cbrMaxPackets = new JTextField[noTCPFlows];

        //Expo contents
        JLabel[] jL1Expo = new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JLabel[] jL2Expo = new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JLabel[] jL3Expo = new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JLabel[] jL4Expo = new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JTextField[] expoPacketSize = new JTextField[noTCPFlows];
        JTextField[] expoRate = new JTextField[noTCPFlows];
        JTextField[] expoBurstTime = new JTextField[noTCPFlows];
        JTextField[] expoIdealTime = new JTextField[noTCPFlows];

        //FTP Contents
        JLabel[] jL1Ftp = new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JLabel[] jL2Ftp = new JLabel[noTCPFlows];
        JTextField[] ftpMaxPackets = new JTextField[noTCPFlows];
        JTextField[] ftpMoreCountPackets = new JTextField[noTCPFlows];

        JPanel[] jP2 = new JPanel[noTCPFlows];
        CardLayout[] layPanelCard = new CardLayout[noTCPFlows];

        for( int i = 0; i<noTCPFlows; i++) {

            //create a new tab & set title
            jP[i] = new JPanel();
            jP[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

            countTcp++;
            //create the flow type label and combo box
            jL[i] = new JLabel("Flow Type:");
            jCb[i] = new JComboBox(flowType);

            //create the options panels

            //CBR Panel
            cbrParams[i] = new JPanel();
            jL1Cbr[i] = new JLabel("Packet Size");
            cbrPacketSize[i] = new JTextField();
            jL2Cbr[i] = new JLabel("Rate");
            cbrRate[i] = new JTextField();
            jL3Cbr[i] = new JLabel("Inter Packet Interval");
            cbrInterPacketInt[i] = new JTextField();
            jL4Cbr[i] = new JLabel("Maximum Packets");
            cbrMaxPackets[i] = new JTextField();
            cbrParams[i].add(jL1Cbr[i]);
            cbrParams[i].add(cbrPacketSize[i]);
            cbrParams[i].add(jL2Cbr[i]);
            cbrParams[i].add(cbrRate[i]);
            cbrParams[i].add(jL3Cbr[i]);
            cbrParams[i].add(cbrInterPacketInt[i]);
            cbrParams[i].add(jL4Cbr[i]);
            cbrParams[i].add(cbrMaxPackets[i]);

            //Expo Panel
            expoParams[i] = new JPanel();
            jL1Expo[i] = new JLabel("Packet Size");
            expoPacketSize[i] = new JTextField();
            jL2Expo[i] = new JLabel("Rate");
            expoRate[i] = new JTextField();
            jL3Expo[i] = new JLabel("Burst Time");
            expoBurstTime[i] = new JTextField();
            jL4Expo[i] = new JLabel("Ideal Time");
            expoIdealTime[i] = new JTextField();
            expoParams[i].add(jL1Expo[i]);
            expoParams[i].add(cbrPacketSize[i]);
            expoParams[i].add(jL2Expo[i]);
            expoParams[i].add(cbrRate[i]);
            expoParams[i].add(jL3Expo[i]);
            expoParams[i].add(cbrInterPacketInt[i]);
            expoParams[i].add(jL4Expo[i]);
            expoParams[i].add(cbrMaxPackets[i]);

            //FTP Panel
            ftpParams[i] = new JPanel();
            jL1Ftp[i] = new JLabel("Max Number Packets");
            ftpMaxPackets[i] = new JTextField();
            jL2Ftp[i] = new JLabel("More Count Packets");
            ftpMoreCountPackets[i] = new JTextField();


            //create a CardLayout for the options presented
            layPanelCard[i] = new  CardLayout();
            jP2[i].setLayout(layPanelCard[i]);
            jP2[i].add("cbrParams",cbrParams[i]);
            jP2[i].add("expoParams",expoParams[i]);
            jP2[i].add("ftpParams",ftpParams[i]);
            layPanelCard[i].show(jP2[i],"cbrParams");

            //add it all to the tab
            jP[i].add(jL[i]);
            jP[i].add(jCb[i]);
            jP[i].add(jP2[i]);

            //add the tab to the tabbedPane

            trafficInfo.addTab(tabName+i,jP[i]);
           //trafficInfo.setTitleAt(countTcp,tcpLabel);

        }
        trafficInfo.updateUI();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ns2GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ns2GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ns2GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ns2GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ns2GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     

}
```

Comment: Don't use the `updateUI()` method. That method is used when the LAF is changed. You have too many Arrays. For related data you should create a custom Object to store this data. Then you add the Object to an ArrayList (since an ArrayList is more dynamic than an Array). Also, you GUI looks rather complicated since you are creating individual Swing components for all the data. Maybe you should be using a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). Also, the posted code doesn't compile. You need to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Fixed! The problem was that one of the JPanel were not initialized. Thanks for trying everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I had forgotten to initialize the JPanel after the JPanel array declaration.

```
//did this
JPanel[] jP2 = new JPanel[noTCPFlows];

//rest of the code

//forgot to add this line
JPanel jP2[i] = new JPanel();
```

Initializing the JPanel fixed all the issues.
Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

```
trafficInfo.setTitleAt(countTcp, tcpLabel+i);
```

Looks like the `countTcp` is somehow incorrect. May be is not initialized properly

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the label and checked it. Even commented this line and tried. Still not working.

Comment: I am sorry my mistake. The problem is countTcp index.

Comment: The stacktrace said that your are trying to set title to tab 1 but there is 0 tabs

Comment: I tried commenting that line but still no success. I will edit the question and post the whole program.